# Ignite UI tree grid is not updaing the table with new data

Tags: javascript, angularjs, infragistics, ignite-ui

I am integrating the Ignite UI tree grid angular directive in my application . I am initializing the grid with empty data source because data is loaded from server, and then assigning the data from server to datasource of tree grid but it is not updating the data in the table. When i use the ig grid directive then it is working but when i use the ig grid tree directive it is not working. If some one wants to see the code i can share it. 
      This is my div element for binding the ig grid as an attribute.

```
  <div ng-controller= "gridController">
 <div  id="gridMyGrid" ig-tree-grid="gridOptions" ></div>
  </div>
```

This is code in my controller with  a grid options object.

```
    angular.module('gridModule',['igniteui-directives'])
  .controller('gridController',function($scope){
      var  realObject = [
                         {"p_l": 68,
    "total_p_l": 68,
    "delta_notional_gross": 0,
    "delta_notional_log": 0,
    "delta_notional_short": 0,
    "delta": 0,
    "gamma": 0,
    "vega": 0,
    "theta": 0,
    "implied_volatility": 0,
    "beta": 0,
    "portfolio_hvar": 0,
    "historical_value_at_risk": 0,
    "secpxs_down_100bps": 0,
    "sec_pxs_plus15percent": 0,
    "sec_pxs_minus15percent": 0,
    "name": "LN 200",
    "qunatity": 200,
    "share_details": []
           }
                ]
        $scope.realObject =[];
          var options = {
                    primaryKey: "name",
                    childDataKey: "share_details",
                    width: '100%',
                    height: 400,
                    autoGenerateColumns: true,


                    dataSource: $scope.realObject,
                    features: [


                        {
                            name: "ColumnMoving",
                            columnMovingDialogContainment: "window"
                        }
                    ]
                };
      $scope.gridOptions = options;


           $timeout(function(){
                                $scope.realObject.push(realObject[2]);
                                $scope.gridOptions.dataSource = $scope.realObject;


                            },5000)
})
```

Any help is appreciated.

Adding the examples on js fiddle what i am expecting.
The link without tree structure and updating the data 
[Link for JS Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/jahanzaib_khan/4sz9kn84/)

The link with tree structure which is not updating the data.
[Link for JS Fiddle with Tree structure](http://jsfiddle.net/jahanzaib_khan/xsnx9v4L/5/)

Answer (score 2):

igTreeGrid doesn't have Two way data-binding support for AngularJS.(igGrid does)

So you need to manually dataBind the igTreeGrid. I modified the sample the with the manual data bind.

```
$("#grid1").igTreeGrid("dataBind");
```

[Link to JS Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/4sz9kn84/1/)

Or you can use the [igTreeGridUpdating](http://www.igniteui.com/help/api/2016.1/ui.igtreegridupdating) api to change the data instead of changing the scope data.

Comment: @dkamurov   i am curious that it is working fine in "IG Grid without using your solution then why we have to use $("grid1").igTreeGrid("dataBind") when we  are integrating the "IG Tree Grid".

Comment: @dkamurov another thing is that on the documentation of Ignite UI it is written that igtreeGrid support one way data binding which is when user  update the data source it will be reflected to the grid and will update the view for new or updated source but it is not even working with one way data binding.

Comment: igTreeGrid does not provide two way data-binding support for AngularJS,(it may be introduced in some point) the one way data-binding support is if you update the data through the Updating API this change will be reflected into the scope.

Comment: can you just give an example for updating the data through updating api it will be helpfull.

Comment: Sure, there you go http://jsfiddle.net/4sz9kn84/2/ . This is the Api $("#grid1").igTreeGridUpdating("updateRow",  0,  {tasks:   "Task Changed"});

Comment: But if i have 100,000 rows then i have to update each row through a loop?

Comment: If you have 100,000 rows you better assign the new data source and call dataBind it will be faster